# Visual Studio cant start to code C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't start coding as the Visual Studio 2017 says that it's corrupted and you have to reinstall in and I reinstalled it and also installed dotnet core sdk too but still no luck. I want C# because i am trying to make some new games of my own using unity engine in my PC.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: You can try to reinstall Windows too...

Answer (score 0):

Run the visual studio installer and try repairing it. If this does'n work you should try unistalling visual studio with revo uninstaller and delete all the pastes and files of it. Then you can install again...